# Post processer for extracting a value from the URL in the request method

Tags: jmeter

I am sending a formed request after login to server and from that formed URL I want to retrieve from URL, using an of the `PostProcesser` like `BeanShell` or `JSR223`.

Request URL :

```
https://localhost:9093/api/events/audit/c0c47b94-f158-4291-ac04-5768850c2ad1/push/10
```

Want to extract following value from the request URL:

```
c0c47b94-f158-4291-ac04-5768850c2ad1
```

How to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would suggest go for JSR223 `Postprocesser` (Jmeter also suggest the same),

[image]

details are [here](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor)

For your question, please add the following script using `JSR223 Postprocesser`

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

def requestData = sampler.getUrl().toString();
def pattern = Pattern.compile('^https?://localhost:9033/api/events/audit/([^/]+)/.*$')

def (_, refDATA) = (requestData =~ pattern)[0]
```

`refDATA`, should contain the value you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

With [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) you can use [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) which provides [Find operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_find_operator), something like:

```
def value = (prev.getUrlAsString() =~ /[{]?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-([0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}[}]?/)[0][0]
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69784422/an-error-was-encountered-with-the-requested-page-in-jmeter-even-capture-variab 

can you look and provide solution this?

Answer (score 1):

You will have many options with the Groovy.
Here is another **simple** solution

```
String requestData = sampler.getUrl().toString();
String value = requestData.split("/")[6]
```

[Groovy](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.html#dropRight(java.lang.String,%20int)) provides many more useful functions to work with the strings.